# oracle concat timestmap from current_date

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I hardly try to concat timestamps. Column time, defined as varchar2, contains values like 23:15. Now I want to create a timestamp with today's date and that time, in this example 23.03.18 23:15:00.00000 is expected. The way I'm doing this is

```
to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(current_date),'ddMMyyyy') ||
             to_char(time),'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

and it works. But when field time has value 06:15, I get the message "hour must be between 0 and 23 ". Whatever I try, it's always this message when time value has leading zero. How can that be corrected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution to the problem (given in the OP's comment) was a change to the Java code unrelated to the question asked so this question is resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works OK for me:

```
SQL> WITH test
  2       AS (SELECT '23:15' time FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT '06:15' time FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (
  6            TO_CHAR (CURRENT_DATE, 'ddMMyyyy') || time,
  7            'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') result
  8    FROM test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------
23.03.18 06:15:00,000000000
23.03.18 23:15:00,000000000

SQL>
```

Please, post your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did.

Comment: I've just found the reason. column time is filled by a java application, where leading Zeros were added with String.format("%02d"...). I changed the way of padding Zeros. it's strange, but it works. Learned something again.

Comment: OK then, I'm glad you found the culprit & made it work.

Comment: `TO_CHAR (..., 'ddMMyyyy')` does not match with `TO_TIMESTAMP (..., 'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` It seems to work, however `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE), 'ddMMyyyy') || TIME, 'ddMMyyyyhh24:mi')` would be better. Also `TRUNC(...)` is redundant when you use `TO_CHAR(..., 'ddMMyyyy')`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `TRUNC` on the current date as the `TO_CHAR` will extract only the year-to-day components and you also don't need `TO_CHAR` on the `time` column as it is already a string. Apart from those simplifications, your query works:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81831/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE times ( time ) AS
SELECT '00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '06:45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '18:59' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '23:15' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT time,
       TO_TIMESTAMP(
         TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) || time,
         'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI'
       ) AS current_day_time
FROM   times
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81831/3/0)**:

```
|  TIME |      CURRENT_DAY_TIME |
|-------|-----------------------|
| 00:00 | 2018-03-23 00:00:00.0 |
| 06:45 | 2018-03-23 06:45:00.0 |
| 12:00 | 2018-03-23 12:00:00.0 |
| 18:59 | 2018-03-23 18:59:00.0 |
| 23:15 | 2018-03-23 23:15:00.0 |
```

Answer (score -1):

try other way around: insert a leading 0 if hour < 10

```
to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(current_date),'ddMMyyyy') ||
             to_char(
                       case when substr(time,1,instr(time,':',1,1)-1)<10 
                               then'0'||time  
                            else time 
                       end),'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```